# Object.GetType() also returning project name

Tags: c#, .net, gettype, nameof

Trying to override ToString() and use the GetType() to return the type of the object being used.  It is returning the information but it includes the NameSpace.  The question is how can I strip off the NameSpace and only display the object name.  Here is my code:

```
namespace Trial
{
   class Testing
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         //Variables
         Person[] objectPerson = new Person[5]; //create an array of references
         objectPerson[0] = new Person(10, "John", 35, 1200.00);
         objectPerson[1] = new Person(20, "Jill", 30, 2400.00);
         objectPerson[2] = new Person(30, "Joann", 40, 600.00);
         objectPerson[3] = new Person(40, "Jimmy", 25, 4800.00);
         objectPerson[4] = new Person(50, "Jamie", 45, 300.00);

         for (int y = 0; y < objectPerson.Length; ++y)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(objectPerson[y].ToString());
         }

         Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit . . .");
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
   class Person
   {
      //Data fields
      private int number;
      private string name;
      private int age;
      private double amountDue;

      //Constructors
      public Person(): this(9,"ZZZ",0,0.00)
      {
      }
      public Person(int _Number, string _Name, int _Age, double _AmountDue)
      {
         Number = _Number;
         Name = _Name;
         Age = _Age;
         AmountDue = _AmountDue;
      }
      //Properties
      public int Number
      { 
         get { return number; }
         set { number = value; }
      }
      public string Name
      {
         get { return name; }
         set { name = value; }
      }
      public int Age
      {
         get { return age; }
         set { age = value; }
      }
      public double AmountDue
      {
         get { return amountDue; }
         set { amountDue = value; }
      }

      //Overrides
      public override string ToString()
      {
         return(this.GetType() + ": " + this.Number +  " - " + this.Name + " (" + this.Age.ToString() + "yo) | The total annual ammount is: " + this.AmountDue.ToString("C") + " and the quarterly payment is " + (this.AmountDue / 4).ToString("C"));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can just use `nameof(Person)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `GetType().Name`

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways to represent a `Type` using it's name:

```
typeof(YourClassName).Name //Output is YourClassName.
typeof(YourClassName).FullName //Output is Namespace + YourClassName.
typeof(YourClassName).AssemblyQualifiedName //Output is Namespace + YourClassName + assembly name, version and signature.
```

When you print the type and not choosing one of them, the `Type.ToString` method is invoked instead, which gives you the `Type.FullName` as a deafult string.

Also in C# 6.0 you can use the syntax nameof(YourClassName) which will replace itself with a constant in compile-time which contains the standard name of the type (The following is a decompilation from the next example):

[image: NameOf]

For example I have this code:

```
namespace ConsoleTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program));
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).Name);
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).AssemblyQualifiedName);
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(Program));
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

> ConsoleTests.Program
>
> Program
>
> ConsoleTests.Program
>
> ConsoleTests.Program, ConsoleTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Program

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#-6, you can use the `nameof` operator:

```
var typeName = nameof(Person);
```

Or as others have stated, [`GetType().Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) for the class name which is inherited from `MemberInfo`.

Either way, you can also simplify the concatenation using [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{nameof(Person)}:{Number}-{Name}({Age}yo) |
             Total amount is: {AmountDue:C} 
             and the quarterly payment is: { (AmountDue / 4):C}";
}
```

Comment: Why not `{AmountDue:C}` instead of `{AmountDue.ToString("C")}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Type.Name property - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx